# iOS: Error when trying to customize Navigation bar

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem, autolayout

I'm attempting to customize the title view for the navigation bar and am receiving an error. Here's the relevant code:

```
UIView *topView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    topView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;

     self.navigationItem.titleView=topView;

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"logojim_35.png"];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;
    [topView addSubview:imageView];

    UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;
    titleLabel.text=@"ACPL Mobile";

    [topView addSubview:titleLabel];

    NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(topView,imageView,titleLabel);

    [topView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[imageView]-[titleLabel]|" options:nil metrics:nil views:views]];
```

And here's the error I'm getting:

```
2012-11-13 16:23:51.635 Mobile_ACPL[22177:12b03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. UINavigationBar's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.'
```

Any idea what the problem is?

And yes, Auto Layout is required for my project.

Comment: Do you override `layoutSubviews`? And if you do, do you call `super`?

Comment: In what method is this code being run?

Comment: @JoePasq This is being called in viewDidLoad of a view controller.

Comment: @AlexWayne I am not subclassing UINavigationBar. Do I need to? I was trying to just create a view and assign it to the nav bar's 'titleView' property. It appears that this works as long as I don't try to add constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question: [Building a titleView programmatically with constraints (or generally constructing a view with constraints)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285698/building-a-titleview-programmatically-with-constraints-or-generally-constructin)

The title view doesn't know the x and the y relate to it's parent if you don't set it a frame.